# Why I can not add a new line to a file with shell sed

Tags: shell, sed

In my project, I have a file1.

The content of this file1 is like:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
else
  export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL

# By default, we want umask to get set.
# Current threshold for system .
```

Now I want to add a sentence after:

```
export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL
```

This sentence is

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`","`who`" >> linshi'
```

So i wrote a cmdRecord.sh script:

```
newLine="export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo \"`date +%Y-%m-%d\" \"%H:%M:%S`\",\"`who`\" >> linshi'"

baseLN="export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL"

sed -i '/$baseLN/a$newLine' file1
```

After execute:  sh cmdRecord.sh, The correct content of file1 should be:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
   export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
else
   export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`","`who`" >> linshi'

# By default, we want umask to get set.
# Current threshold for system .
```

But unlucky, it is failed, new sentence is not display in file1.

I have tried:

sed -i "/$baseLN/a$addNL" file1

But the command is executed in new line, the result is:

```
 HISTSIZE=1000
if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
  export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
else
  export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo 2019-07-09 11:45:08,"root  pts/0 2019-07-09 11:38 (ln01)" >> linshi'"

# By default, we want umask to get set.
# Current threshold for system .
```

The new line is changed!!
It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Comment: `sed -i '/$baseLN/a$newLine' file1` withing *single-quotes* prevents variable expansion. At minimum, you would need `sed -i "/$baseLN/a$newLine" file1`, but I am not convinced your original quote-scheme when storing the variables will work. Do you really want an `'a'` before `$newLine`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin，you are right, see my update

Comment: Sed's `a` and `i` are tough to use inline.  Might try something like `s/^.*$baseLN.*$/&\n$newLine/`

Answer (score 0):

```
newLine="export PROMPT_COMMAND=\'echo \"\`date +%Y-%m-%d\" \"%H:%M:%S\`\",\"\`who\`\" >> linshi\'"
```

It works well

Comment: What about `newLine="export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo \"\$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')\",\"\$(who)\" >> linshi'"`? (use `$(...)` for command substitution rather than backticks)

Answer (score 0):

You have to revoke the special meaning of the characters " and ` for the bash with an escape sign :

```
sed "/export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL/a export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo \"\`date +%Y-%m-%d\" \"%H:%M:%S\`\",\"\`who\`\" >> linshi'" file1
```

With the option -i (sed -i ...) you can modify the file inline.

Answer (score 0):

Your first challenge is getting newLine filled like you want.
You can avoid adding backslashes with the syntax of https://serverfault.com/a/72511

```
IFS= read -r -d '' newLine <<"END"
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`","`who`" >> linshi'
END
```

You can make a `sed` command with the

```
baseLN="export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL"
cmd=$(printf "/%s/a%s" "${baseLN}" "${newLine}")
sed "${cmd}" file1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '/export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL/r /dev/stdin' file
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`","`who`" >> linshi'
!
```